# Latest video list display with title and date WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, list, video, title

Looking for WordPress help.

Is it possible to display the "Latest Upload Video" in the media with a List display?

ie. Display the Title and Display the Date uploaded the video with the title link?

[See this screenshot](http://prntscr.com/ftyue1)

Here is my code:

```
<p><span><?php echo the_time("m/d/Y") ?></span></p>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

Can anyone please help?

AR

Answer (score 0):

Never mind guys, I just fixed my problem by using this following code:

```
<?php 
                    query_posts(array('post_type'=>'video_section','posts_per_page'=>'3','order'=>'ASC')); 
                    while(have_posts()) : the_post();
                ?>  
                <p>
                    <span><?php echo the_time("m/d/Y") ?>  </span>
                </p>
                <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                <?php 
                    endwhile; 
                    wp_reset_query(); 
                ?>
```

[Here is the result](http://prntscr.com/fuctsa)